# FFMPEG Raspivid Videos are shorter than they are supposed to be

Tags: ffmpeg, raspivid

I am recording and piping my video with the following command :

```
raspivid -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 25 -b 7000000 -o - -t 0 | ffmpeg -re -f h264 -framerate 25 -i - -vcodec copy -y -r 25 -strict experimental /media/video/testyolol.mp4
```

It does work for some time but the longer the recording is the lower is the speed and the fps drop slightly. I first started at 30 fps and after ~20min the fps was down to 26. And setting the fps to 25 also results in a drop after some time.
Here is the output in the first few seconds :

```
frame=   15 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     439kB time=00:00:00.56 bitrate=6421.2kbits
frame=   27 fps= 27 q=-1.0 size=     891kB time=00:00:01.04 bitrate=7021.2kbits
frame=   40 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=    1352kB time=00:00:01.56 bitrate=7096.9kbits
frame=   52 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=    1754kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate=7044.8kbits
frame=   65 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=    2302kB time=00:00:02.56 bitrate=7365.8kbits
frame=   78 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=    2675kB time=00:00:03.08 bitrate=7115.6kbits
frame=   90 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    3065kB time=00:00:03.56 bitrate=7053.7kbits
frame=  103 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    3508kB time=00:00:04.08 bitrate=7042.8kbits
frame=  116 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    3953kB time=00:00:04.60 bitrate=7039.9kbits
frame=  128 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    4426kB time=00:00:05.08 bitrate=7137.2kbits
frame=  141 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    4828kB time=00:00:05.60 bitrate=7062.7kbits
frame=  153 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    5222kB time=00:00:06.08 bitrate=7036.0kbits
frame=  166 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    5672kB time=00:00:06.60 bitrate=7040.6kbits
```

And here after 20~ min

```
frame=37003 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size= 1264751kB time=00:24:40.08 bitrate=7000.2kbits
frame=37039 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size= 1265996kB time=00:24:41.52 bitrate=7000.3kbits
frame=37052 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size= 1266428kB time=00:24:42.04 bitrate=7000.2kbits
frame=37065 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size= 1266854kB time=00:24:42.56 bitrate=7000.1kbits/
```

As you can see the fps drop to 24 which resulst in the safed file not beeing 25min long if i have recorded for 25min meaning the recording is slightly sped up. Roughly 1min is missing after 20min of recording.

Is there a way to ensure the recorded file is as long as the actual recording and not sped up (important for my current project)?

Comment: why have you added `-strict experimental`?

Comment: i was using different options to improve performance and one user suggested to test it out. But it doesn't matter if i use it or not tbh.

Answer (score 1):

The `-framerate` option before the `-i` basically tells `ffmpeg` to *trust* that the input framerate is what you tell it is, and not rely on frame timestamps. Obviusly, `raspivid` is not holding its part of the deal and doesn't provide steady 25 fps.

Try to let `ffmpeg` find out the framerate on its own by specifying *only* the output framerate (`-r 25` after the `-i`). If that doesn't help, you'll have to find a way to make `raspivid` deliver what you ask for, perhaps settling for less fps or lower resolution.

Comment: i just tried it out with only the output stream set to 25 fps but it was even worse. In a 10min recording the resulting video was only 8min long.

Comment: @huialx That sounds like a bug in `raspivid` which doesn't seem to provide reliable frame timestamps.